# LiipImagineBundle - Symfony

Tags: liipimaginebundle

i install the bundle. LiipImagineBundle to make thumbmails but it's not working.

here is my install:

On the Appkernel

```
 class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            // My admin bundle
            new AdminBundle\AdminBundle(),

            // These are the other bundles the SonataAdminBundle relies on
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(), 

            // And finally, the storage and SonataAdminBundle
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
            new UserBundle\UserBundle(),

            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle()
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

And after in my app/config.yml

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        avatar:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Then my routing :

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

And the last thing i did, in my twig i put the filter

```
{% for image in object.image %}
<li><img style="width: auto; height: 80px; margin: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #d2d6de;" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ image) | imagine_filter('avatar') }}"/></li>

{% endfor %}
```

I have created a folder in my website.
media/cache with CHMOD 777

But the problem is that no pictures is generated !!!
can you help me on this

If i click on a picture with google-development tools of my website, i have noting but a route like this:

```
<img style="width: auto; height: 80px; margin: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #d2d6de;" src="https://test.hello.org/media/cache/resolve/avatar/uploads/documents/TEST-JEUDI.jpg">
```

[PICTURE OF MY DASHBOARD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9pgq.jpg)

Comment: Is it a problem of SERVEUR ???

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this!
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/extra.html

```
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        avatar:
            quality: 75
            controller_action: 'SonataMediaBundle:Media:liipImagineFilter'
            filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [500, 70], mode: outbound }
```

"controller_action: 'SonataMediaBundle:Media:liipImagineFilter' //pay atention hire"

I hope to help You

Comment: I try this with controller_action but it's not working